# Hadoop on windows server: Is HDInsight for windows server supported to run on a Domain Controller?

Tags: hadoop, windows-server-2008-r2, bigdata, azure-hdinsight

On my Demo Machine: I have Windows Server 2008 R2 and it's also domain controller. I installed HDInsight for windows server via Web Platform Installer but I do NOT see a site under IIS using which I can manage my cluster. So just wondering if HDInsight is not supported on a Domain Controller? Or is there any other configuration that I should check. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replied (but I need at least 30 characters to submit something here or Stack Overflow gives me an error indicating my reply is too short): http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/hdinsight/thread/71ba4f1b-af9c-40d7-85e6-db3fbcaa7508

October 31st, 2012 update: Unofficially, Microsoft agrees that installing HDInsight on a server with AD installed is not supported.  Now, I would like to confirm that a domain *member* will be fine, but that will only be in a few days.

Comment: Nice discussion on http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/hdinsight/thread/71ba4f1b-af9c-40d7-85e6-db3fbcaa7508 - Thanks for adding the update here.